# How to access all the rows whose 2 columns have similar values in these rows in Node Js Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using Node Js, MySql (Sequelize) as my backend. [In the image their are three rows against same TeacherId. I want to get the record where TeacherId, SubjectId AND CurriculumId are the SAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOlPo.png)

as like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "CurriculumId": 1,
        "curriculum_name": "UK National Curriculum",
        "SubjectId": 6,
        "subject_name": "Anatomy",
        "doc": [
            {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "abc.zip",
                "path": "https://www.google.com",
                "size": "163 KB",
                "createdAt": "2021-12-30T18:58:52.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "abcc.sql",
                "path": "https://www.oogle.com",
                "size": "1613 KB",
                "createdAt": "2021-12-30T18:58:52.000Z"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "CurriculumId": 2,
        "curriculum_name": "EYFS",
        "SubjectId": 4,
        "subject_name": "Statistics",
        "doc": [
            {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "1642770387740-file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf",
                "path": "https://app.edukko.com/api/uploads/teacherDocuments/1642770387740-file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf",
                "size": "1018.00 KB",
                "createdAt": "2022-01-21T13:06:27.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can specify your condition in WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks. But How to do that? Can you please explain?

Comment: I've not used sequelizer yet, but in mysql your query would be like: `SELECT* FROM tableName WHERE SubjectId = 6 AND CurriculumId = 1 AND TeacherId = 18`.